# Calling Java Stored Procedure in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a Java stored procedure for Oracle, following
[Example 7-2 Fibonacci Sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chseven.htm#CACIBAHF).

I have gone through exactly the same process, but while executing the code

```
SQL> VARIABLE n NUMBER
SQL> VARIABLE f NUMBER
SQL> EXECUTE :n := 7;
SQL> CALL fib(:n) INTO :f;
```

I get following response:

```
anonymous block completed

Error starting at line 4 in command:
CALL fib(:n) INTO :f
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
01008. 00000 -  "not all variables bound"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle docs have a lot of coding errors in them (sometimes omissions, sometimes bugs)... anyway, I think the issue is with how that class got loaded.

Try loading the class like this:

```
create or replace and compile java source named Fibonacci as
public class Fibonacci
{
  public static int fib (int n)
  {
    if (n == 1 || n == 2)
      return 1;
    else
      return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
  }
}
```

Make sure the function wrapper is valid and try again.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fib (n NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'Fibonacci.fib(int) return int';
```

I got the correct output when I tried it.

```
SQL> VARIABLE n NUMBER
SQL> VARIABLE f NUMBER
SQL> EXECUTE :n := 7;
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
n
---------
7
SQL> CALL fib(:n) INTO :f;
Method called
n
---------
7
f
---------
13
SQL> PRINT f
f
---------
13
```

Comment: Done this on SQL Developer but still getting the same error. i think  i am missing something that is understood

Comment: CALL fib(:n) INTO :f;

line is causing problem while executing in SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about the SQL Developer product and what's above might only work in SQL Plus.

Try:

```
SELECT fib(7) FROM dual;
```